# Nested routes inside Switch

Tags: reactjs, react-router

On my **index.js** i have the following

```
var indexRoutes = [
    { path: "/", name: "Homepage", component: Home},
    { path: "/dashboard", name: "Dashboard", component: Dashboard },
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <HashRouter>
    <Switch>
      {indexRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
        return <Route path={prop.path} component={prop.component} exact/>;
      })}
      <Route component={Homepage} />
    </Switch>
  </HashRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Basically, the `Home` component would have the front-page, login and registration, as it follows:

```
<div className="app-container">
    <Header/>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Visitor} exact/>
        <Route path="/register" component={Register} exact/>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} exact />
        <Route component={NotFound}/>
    </Switch>
    <Footer/>
</div>
```

To this point, everything works alright. But then, when i try to use nested routes on the dashboard, they don't work.

```
const dashboardRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    name: "Dashboard",
    icon: "pe-7s-graph",
    component: Dashboard
  },
  {
    path: "/dashboard/tours",
    name: "Tours",
    icon: "pe-7s-plane",
    component: Tours
  },
  {
    path: "/dashboard/user",
    name: "User Profile",
    icon: "pe-7s-user",
    component: UserProfile
  }] 

 render() {

    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <Sidebar {...this.props} />
        <div id="main-panel" className="main-panel" ref="mainPanel">
          <Header {...this.props} />
          <Switch>


              if (prop.redirect)
                return <Redirect from={prop.path} to={prop.to} key={key} />;
              else 
                return <Route path={prop.path} component={prop.component} exact />


            })}
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

/register /login and /dashboard all work allright. But when i try to access, for example /dashboard/user it shows me the NotFound page, from the `Home` component.

What am i doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `exact` parameter for the `/dashboard` route. Based on the [official docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool) it won't match anything further than `/dashboard`. Your index.js should have `return <Route path={prop.path} component={prop.component} />`

```
path    location.pathname   exact   matches?
/one    /one/two            false   yes
/one    /one/two            true    no
```

**Edit:** Based on your recursive approach I would put the `exact` parameter in your array and then render if true.

```
var indexRoutes = [
    { path: "/", name: "Homepage", component: Home, exact: true},
    { path: "/dashboard", name: "Dashboard", component: Dashboard, exact: false },
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <HashRouter>
    <Switch>
      {indexRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
        return <Route path={prop.path} component={prop.component} exact={prop.exact} />;
      })}
      <Route component={Homepage} />
    </Switch>
  </HashRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Now that i made that change, the `/dashboard` route redirects me to the `NotFound` page.

Comment: @spacecows I'll make an edit which might help that issue

Comment: thank you so much, that solved it. spent some good time on this!

Comment: Glad to be of help!